# C or C++ for EE

Tags: c, programming, c++

I am a freshman EE student looking to have an emphasis in computer engineering. I do not start my core engineering classes till next year. However, I am wanting to get a jump on learning a "close to the metal" programming language. **Should I learn C or C++?** Or any other language for that matter.

Comment: You are asking for an opinion and that's off-topic

Comment: I'd argue that C is much more used in embedded systems than C++, especially those close to the metal.

Comment: Besides on opinions, personal preference, moonphase and religion, an answer depends on what you actually mean by "embedded". The answers then range from "don't, learn assembler" to "learn C" to "learn C++ and learn it really good to know which parts to avoid"

Comment: @Tut: That is a common misconception. While they both have the same origins, and have a common subset, C has never been a subset of C++, there has always been lots of C that is not C++, and with every new standard these difference grow. Not to talk about how different your spirit of thinking has to be to be good in either language.

Comment: C++ is an object-oriented language, which is more commonly used in computer programming. C is more commonly used in embedded systems. Either way I still recommend learning C first. Once you know C, it is much easier to learn object-oriented languages like C++, C#, or Java

Comment: Learn how to think in programming. Learn algorithms, data structures. The language doesnt matter. That's syntax.

Comment: @derstrom8 there is a lot in C++ that is very usefull (in general and for close-to-the-hardware work) yet has nothing to do with OO, like a better type system, templates, and constexpr. And a limited OO (without virtuals) to create ADTs can be very usefull too (and with 0 run-time overhead).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen You're absolutely right, I was speaking very generally from a beginner's point of view

Comment: @derstrom8: Another misconception. C++ is not just an OO language, it is a multi paradigm language that contains elements of OO, generic, imperative and functional programming. See http://www.stroustrup.com/oopsla.pdf

Comment: @PlasmaHH see my last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for an opinion, so consider this a long comment rather than an answer. First: I don't think there are other languages to consider. The only contender was Ada, but IMO it has fallen far behind.

Embedded, and even close-to-the-metal, encompasses a wide range of target hardware, from tiny sub-1k FLASH 8-bit or even 4-bit micro-controllers, up to GHz micro-processors (and don't forget the GPU's!). On the extreme small side assembler might be a good choice in some cases, on the other extreme C++ is IMO the only good choice.

That reduces the question to where the two switchover points are: where to ditch assembler and use C, and where to dicth C and use C++. That depends on too many factors to give a straight answer, but my take would be: use the highest language that is feasible. If you have a full C++ compiler available, use C++. If not (8-bit chips) use C. In the rare case that C does not give you enough control, use assembler.

(Unfortunately the AVR C/C++ compilers are seriously hapered by the split-memory model use in the AVR. And the PICs, well....)

My bullet points are

- if you are using anything else, switch to ARM/Cortex NOW
- in nearly all cases, you will be better off using C++
- but that is NOT the C++ 'style' that is used on the desktop
- even though C and C++ differ a lot, there is a common subset that is usefull to learn for close-to-the-hardware programming, indepent of which one you will use later. Learn this first.  Avoid C idioms (malloc, most MACROs, etc) that are done differently (and better) in C++, and avoid the C++ idioms that are specific for large-system programming (ANYTHING that uses the heap, RTTI, and probably exceptions too).

You can google "objects no thanks" for how I think C++ should be used on small/close-to-the-hardware system.

Note that I describe what *I think* one should do, which is not *how it is done now*: current practice is more towards the left (especially more C where I would prefer C++). You might take that into account in your career planning. Of course things can be different in a few years, especially if I can do enaything about it. But things havn't moved much in the last decades, don't put all your eggs in one basket.

PS thumbs up for specifically asking about close-to-the-hardware instead of using the much to general terms micro-controller or embedded.

PS although in principle I agree with the SE rule of 'answers must be objectively correct' I would like to see a place where you can ask for (good?) opinions.

Comment: In what sense has Ada fallen behind? If you mean the 1983 version, fair enough but Ada-2012 is quite a different beast, and  certainly available on AVR and ARM-Cortex. (MSP430 if you're willing to dig a bit). I'm interested because I hear negative opinions about Ada quite a lot, but never any substantive reasons against it except difficulty finding tools. I'll add tnat I really like it and it's exceptionally good at programming close to the metal.

Comment: I admit that I havn't studied the recent Ada versions, my experience has been with Ada 83 and 95. Has Ada-2012 C++-like templates (especially specialization and SFINAE) and constexpr? (But my remark refers more to Ada and its lack of use, exposure, libraries, books, etc. than to the language propper.)

Comment: Heh, none of my C++ books even mention constexpr, and one of them regards templates as new and a bit experimental... Ada's had generics (less catastrophe-prone than templates but a bit less flexible) since 83. I can't see what constexpr would bring to Ada since any decent compiler already evaluates anything it can at compile time. (This may not have been true for 1980's era compilers) "Constant" has never had the problems that C's "const" does. I'd regard Ada-95 as still relevant and useful, but not 83.

Comment: Re: SFINAE - again it's not even relevant. If you can get a generic to compile, any legal instantiation (i.e. that also compiles) will work.

Comment: The C++ that I find (very) usefull in small embedded systems is at least 0x11, better 0x14. 'any decent compiler...' is that true? Constexpr *requires* it, as a language feature, and forces your implementation to support it. If your latest C++ book regards templates as experimental you might check a newer book: I am talking about a very different language than you have in mind.

Comment: I don't think you get wat SFINAE is about: it means compile-time templates are a (Turing-complete) langauge in itself. For bettre or for worse...

Comment: What I recall from Ada83/95 is that Ada took what Ichbiah & co tought to be good use cases for C++-like features and put them in the language, and they blocked the bad use-cases. The good consequence is that it is more difficult to do stupid sthings in Ada (compared to C/C++). The bad consequence is that it is difficult or impossible to do good things that the designers did not think of (or rejected). In C++ you can do those good things, but with that comes a lot of opportunities to to bad things that are simply impossible in Ada.

Comment: No, it was my oldest C++ book that regarded templates as new. C++ has added a LOT of stuff since then and I haven't had any need to keep up with 11 or 14. Skimmed the 11/14 features, looks like C++ is finally catching up if you can ignore the quicksand underneath. You are correct that I'm not up to speed with SFINAE though!

Comment: From my experience, the majority of microchips support C over C++, especially for the cheaper 8-bit controllers. The 32bit microcontrollers seem to have more C++ support, but it is still very limited. [Just saw this question has been closed for some time. Not sure why it popped up in recently asked.]

Comment: Sure, no C++ for 8051 and small PICs. But nearly all other reasonable targets are supported by gcc and/or clang. If only I had enough time I would (re)create a gcc C-backend to bring C++ to those small 8-bitters too.

Comment: In what sense is the C++ support for 32-bitters still limited?